# Retrieve Value From Xml Attributes

Tags: .net, xml

i want to get some value from xml file filtering with xml attribute.
my xml format is like below.

```
<Object type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox">    
    <Property name="Name">RadioButton1</Property>
    <Property name="Size">86, 24</Property>    
    <Property name="Text">RadioButton1</Property>
    <Property name="Location">175, 126</Property>    
</Object>
```

for example,

if name = "Name" then i will add its value to name textbox.

if name = "Size" then i will add its value to size textbox.

regards

Chong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlDocument doc  = new xmlDocument()

doc.LaodXml(xmlString);
TextBox1.Text = doc.SelectSingle("Object/Property[@name='name']").attributes[0].value == "name"? 
doc.SelectSingle("Object/Property[@name='Name']").InnerText: string.Empty;
//do the same for the next attribute you want
```

This is a C# version

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry,i didn't find the selectsingle,is it SelectSingleNode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion too lookup through all controls in the form and apply your xml to its properties (for example: for every control type you can create specific class that will be taken for that type - you can use dictionary for that (i.e. `controls[control.GetType()].ApplySettings(xml)` ).